# Using xpath on a stream

Tags: c#, xml, stream, streamreader

is it possible to use xpath on a streamed xml file using streamreader (file obtained from the internet) ?

I know the exact location of the data i need but not sure how best to get at it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the `XDocument.Load(Stream, LoadOptions)` method to parse the XML out of the stream. Then you can use `XDocument.XPathEvaluate` to get the value.

Answer (score 1):

While it would be theoretically possible to build a stream reader that executed an XPath query on a stream, I don't know of any such implementation; the XPath processors in the .NET framework (in `XDocument`, `XmlDocument`, and `XPathDocument`) all read the document into memory before executing the query.  All of these objects can read streams.

If speed is a concern, `XPathDocument` and `XPathNavigator` are likely to be the fastest, since those objects let you directly iterate over the nodes as the query executes, rather than executing the query and returning a list of nodes for you to iterate over.  (Actually `XDocument.XPathEvaluate` may do this too; the documentation doesn't say.)